# WPF. Изображение не отображается при запуске программы

Tags: wpf

В обозревателе все как надо, а когда запускаю программу картинка пропадает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В свойствах картинки укажите как ресурс, либо копируйте в директорию рядом с .exe

Comment: До этого он был у эгзешника и все было так же. В свойствах поменял на Ресурс. Безрезультатно.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так, мне помогло когда нужно было

```
<Grid.Background>
   <ImageBrush ImageSource="D:\Resource\Background.jpg" />
</Grid.Background>
```